# App Store review integration

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'd like to know how to put that menu inside my app that asks the user to review my app and redirects him to App Store to do so. Searched around but couldn't find much information, probably I'm not using the right keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AppIRater is too heavy for you, you can send them directly to the page by using the format:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID
```

… where `APP_ID` is your iTunes numerical application id.

Comment: I have since released a nice library for this: http://github.com/UrbanApps/UAAppReviewManager

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice library called [Appirater](http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/) for that.

Comment: AppIRater is no longer the best library for this: http://github.com/UrbanApps/UAAppReviewManager